# Booking database design with a twist

Tags: database-design

I'm wanting to find a way to how I can implement a booking system that lets users put a start date on the booking and generate the end date whenever.

Lets take a house renting example. Say I wanted to book a house from a particular ***starting date***, but I'm not sure when I'll leave, the maximum stay for users who don't put a ***end date*** is 3 days, how could I do build my database so there aren't any ***booking*** overlaps?

The current structure I have is:

#### booking

```
booking_id      | integer | not null default nextval('booking_booking_id_seq'::regclass)
houseId | integer |
user_id         | integer | not null
```

#### booking_date

```
 booking_date_id | integer                     | not null default nextval('booking_date_booking_date_id_seq'::regclass)
 book_from       | timestamp without time zone | not null
 book_to         | timestamp without time zone | not null
 booking_id      | integer                     |
```

I'm wondering whether I store an extra field in the booking entity ***is_stayAndLeaveWhenever***

and then in the booking_date I'd just store the ***book_to*** with the book_from + 3 days (max stay without choosing leave date)

Is that a solid solution?

Comment: Why 2 entities? Is `booking` supposed to have multiple `booking_date`?

Comment: Good point...But building it this way means if I ever want todo something fancy with the booking -> booking_dates, I can. @Serg

Comment: OK then why not 3 entities, separating book_from  and book_to ?

Comment: Seems pointless doing that @Serg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the maximum stay for users who don't put a end date is 3 days,

Default end date in db = 3 days. Maybe marker "tentative". Issue being - if you do not know when they move out and can not have overlap, you MUST reserve the maximum stay.

So, your solution is as good as it gets.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right. Was just thinking there may be a smarter way of doing this!

Comment: Any idea how I'd implement a billing service for each of the bookings? If you could point me towards a tutorial or example that'd be great!